# How to add Jitsi Meet to Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, jitsi

I have loaded the jitsi meet script in the body of my public.html, and i have a component as follows:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="meet"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "ServiceMeet",
  mounted() {
    const domain = "meet.jit.si";
    const options = {
      roomName: "PickAnAppropriateMeetingNameHere",
      width: 700,
      height: 700,
      parentNode: document.querySelector("#meet"),
    };
    const api = new JitsiMeetExternalAPI(domain, options);
    console.log(api.getVideoQuality());
  },
};
</script>
```

When I try to run I get an error saying `18:21  error  'JitsiMeetExternalAPI' is not defined  no-undef`, however in the background i can see that the meet is working fine, so I do I fix the error or dismiss it.

Comment: UPDATE: Don't suggest any linter ignores as I've already done this but still get an undefined error.

Answer (score 2):

You could disable the linting error, but I would recommend specifying it as a [global variable](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-globals) instead.

**`.eslintrc.js`**

```js
module.exports = {
  globals: {
    JitsiMeetExternalAPI: true
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work as it cant parse any of the .vue files.

Comment: @svoruganti What do you mean by that? ESLint *does* parse `.vue` files. I verified this answer works in my sandbox (a new project generated from Vue CLI).

Answer (score 1):

It should work if you prefix the global with `window`:

```js
const api = new window.JitsiMeetExternalAPI(domain, options);
```