# Is there a nice way to wrap a JQuery based widget into a module that can be easily used in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

Some colleagues of mine have began a fairly complex web application using Vue.js. They would like to be able to use some of the widgets I've made from scratch in the past using JQuery, as re-implementing them would  require a large amount of effort/time.

I know that it's possible to safely use JQuery with Vue.js if you are careful, but the information I've been able to find seems relegated to fairly vague blog posts, and my colleagues have notified me that they are struggling to figure out how to do it. So I am considering the possibility that I could find a way that I can nicely wrap my widgets into a portable cross framework library (for starters that can be used in Vue.js). For example, similar to how people create bindings that provide across language APIs. Ideally, it should make it very easy for someone to use it with Vue.js, and should take away the danger of potential pitfalls. Is there any problem with doing this, and is there any existing work that can be leveraged, or idiomatic way that people do this?

For added context, currently, the widget has an interface that includes a constructor (in which you pass the id of a parent DOM element that it will be appended to), a configure function, and it also emits several signals/events when it changes (although, those could be replaced by a function that checks it's state periodically).

Comment: @FSDford - read the first sentence - and jquery IS javascript :p

Comment: @mvtc - Are you using just jquery or customized jquery-ui component? If your component uses jquery only, it's possible that you can use it in vue.

Comment: @StefanWang It uses jquery-ui draggable internally, I guess I could probably redo that part with just jquery.

Comment: @MVTC, I agree with you. In my exp, using jquery only works really fine in vue, but not jquery-ui if the component should interact with vue ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as creating a portable and cross-framework library is concerned, I would think of jQuery as simply a dependency that allows you create certain elements and perform certain tasks, which you would intercept and/or modify according to the target framework's requirements. So, you are essentially creating a wrapper **component** around it, as the top 3 JavaScript frameworks (React, Vue, Angular) today are component-based.

One of the key differences (simply put) is: Reactivity system vs. DOM manipulation.

Now, talking about porting a jQuery plugin to Vue — I'm no expert in both libraries but coming from jQuery myself, I'd say it could be as easy as keeping a reference to a widget/plugin instance on a Vue component internal `data` and/or `props` and having it *optionally* expose the corresponding methods. The reason for the methods exposure part being optional is the same reason that characterizes one library from the other—Vue being more versatile as it scales between both a library and a framework.

In jQuery, you would create an instance of an object and pass it around for its public methods usages; whereas in Vue, you don't explicitly create instances except for the root one (you [could](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-extend), but you typically won't have to)—because the component itself ***is*** the (internally constructed) instance. And it is the responsibility of a component to maintain its states and data; the sibling and/or parent components will typically have no **direct** access to them.

Vue and jQuery are similar in that they both support state/data synchronization. With jQuery, it's obvious since all references are in the global scope; with Vue, one would use either [`v-model`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-model) or the [`.sync`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier) modifier (replaced with arguments on `v-model` in Vue 3). Additionally, they also have event subscription with slightly different approaches.

Let's take the jQuery [Autocomplete widget](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) and add some Vue support to it. We'll be focusing on 3 things (Options, Events and Methods) and take 3 of their respective items as an example and comparison. I cannot cover everything here, but this should give you some basic ideas.

### Setting up: jQuery

For the sake of complying with your specification in question, let's assume this widget/plugin is a `new`-able class in the `window` scope.

In jQuery, you would write the following (on `document` ready or wrapped in IIFE before the closing `<body>` tag):

```js
var autocomplete = new Autocomplete({
  source: [
    'vue',
    'react',
    'angular',
    'jquery'
  ],
  appendTo: '#autocomplete-container', 
  disabled: false,

  change: function(event, ui) { },
  focus: function(event, ui) { },
  select: function(event, ui) { }
});

// And then some other place needing manual triggers on this instance
autocomplete.close();

var isDisabled = autocomplete.option('disabled');

autocomplete.search('ue'); // Matches 'vue' and 'jquery' ;)
```

With the target element pre-defined or dynamically created somewhere in the parent scope:

```html
<input type="search" class="my-autocomplete" />
```

### Porting to Vue

Since you didn't mention any specific version of Vue in use, I'm going to assume the *Macross* (latest stable version: 2.6.12, ATTOW) with ES module; otherwise, try the ES modules [compatible build](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#CDN).

And for this particular use case in Vue, we want to instantiate this plugin in the [`mounted`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted) hook, because this is where our target element will have been created and available to literally build upon. Learn more on the Lifecycle Hooks in a diagram [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram).

#### Creating component: `Autocomplete.vue`

```html
<template>
  <!-- 
    Notice how this `input` element is added right here rather than we requiring 
    the parent component to add one, because it's now part of the component. :)
    -->
  <input type="search" class="my-autocomplete" />
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    // Basically, this is where you define IMMUTABLE "options", so to speak.
    props: {
      source: {
        type: Array,
        default: () => []
      },

      disabled: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
      }
    },

    // And this is where to prepare and/or specify the internal options of a component.
    data: () => ({
      instance: null
    }),

    mounted() {
      // `this` here refers to the local Vue instance

      this.instance = new Autocomplete({
        source: this.source,
        disabled: this.disabled,
        appendTo: this.$el // Refers to the `input` element on the template,

        change: (event, ui) => {
          // You can optionally pass anything in the second argument
          this.$emit('change', this.instance);
        },

        focus: (event, ui) => {
          this.$emit('focus', this.instance, event);
        },

        select: (event, ui) => {
          this.$emit('select', this, event, ui);
        }
      });
    },

    methods: {
      close() {
        this.instance.autocomplete('close');
      },

      getOption(optionName) {
        return this.instance.autocomplete('option', optionName);
      },

      search(keyword) {
        this.instance.autocomplete('search', keyword);
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

#### Using the component: `Parent.vue` (or whatever)

```html
<template>
  <div class="parent">
    <autocomplete
      ref="autocomplete"
      :source="items"
      :disabled="disabled"
      @change="onChange"
      @focus="onFocus"
      @select="onSelect">
    </autocomplete>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Autocomplete from 'path/to/your-components/Autocomplete.vue';

  export default {
    data: () => ({
      items: [
        'vue',
        'react',
        'angular',
        'jquery'
      ],
      disabled: false
    }),

    methods: {
      onChange() {
      },

      onFocus() {
      },

      onSelect() {
      }
    },

    mounted() {
      // Manually invoke a public method as soon as the component is ready
      this.$refs.autocomplete.search('ue');
    },

    components: {
      Autocomplete
    }
  }
</script>
```

And we're not there just yet! I purposefully left out the ["two-way binding"](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html) portion of the above example for us to take a closer look at now. However, this step is optional and should only be done if you need to synchronize data/state between the components (parent ↔ child), for example: You have some logic on the component that sets the input's border color to red when certain values get entered. Now, since you are modifying the parent state (say `invalid` or `error`) bound to this component as a prop, you need inform them of its changes by [`$emit`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-emit)-ting the new value.

So, let's make the following changes (on the same `Autocomplete.vue` component, with everything else omitted for brevity):

```js
{
  model: {
    prop: 'source',
    event: 'modified' // Custom event name
  },

  async created() {
    // An example of fetching remote data and updating the `source` property.
    const newSource = await axios.post('api/fetch-data').then(res => res.data);

    // Once fetched, update the jQuery-wrapped autocomplete
    this.instance.autocomplete('option', 'source', newSource);

    // and tell the parent that it has changed
    this.$emit('modified', newSource);
  },

  watch: {
    source(newData, oldData) {
      this.instance.autocomplete('option', 'source', newData);
    }
  }
}
```

We're basically `watch`-ing "eagerly" for data changes. If preferred, you could do it lazily with the [`$watch`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-watch) instance method.

Required changes on the parent side:

```html
<template>
  <div class="parent">
    <autocomplete
      ref="autocomplete"
      v-model="items"
      :disabled="disabled"
      @change="onChange"
      @focus="onFocus"
      @select="onSelect">
    </autocomplete>
  </div>
</template>
```

That's going to enable the aforementioned two-way binding. You could do the same with the rest of the props that you need be "reactive", like the `disabled` prop in this example—only this time you would use `.sync` modifier; because in Vue 2, multiple `v-model` isn't supported. (If you haven't got too far though, I'd suggest going for Vue 3 all the way ).

Finally, there are some caveats and common gotchas that you might want to look out for:

- Since Vue performs DOM updates asynchronously, it could be processing something that won't take effect until the [next event loop "tick"](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick), read more on [Async Update Queue](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Async-Update-Queue).
- Due to limitations in JavaScript, there are types of changes that Vue **cannot detect**. However, there are [ways to circumvent them](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats) to preserve reactivity.
- The `this` object being `undefined`, `null` or in unexpected instance when referenced within a nested method or external function. Go to [the docs](https://vuejs.org/) and search for "arrow function" for complete explanation and how to avoid running into this issue.

And we've created ourselves a Vue-ported version of jQuery Autocomplete! And again, those are just some basic ideas to get you started.

#### Live Demo

```js
const Autocomplete = Vue.extend({
  template: `
    <div class="autocomplete-wrapper">
      <p>{{label}}</p>
      <input type="search" class="my-autocomplete" />
    </div>
  `,

  props: {
    source: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => []
    },

    disabled: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },

    label: {
      type: String
    }
  },

  model: {
    prop: 'source',
    event: 'modified'
  },

  data: () => ({
    instance: null
  }),

  mounted() {
    const el = this.$el.querySelector('input.my-autocomplete');

    this.instance = $(el).autocomplete({
      source: this.source,
      disabled: this.disabled,

      change: (event, ui) => {
        // You can optionally pass anything in the second argument
        this.$emit('change', this.instance);
      },

      focus: (event, ui) => {
        this.$emit('focus', this.instance, event);
      },

      select: (event, ui) => {
        this.$emit('select', this, event, ui);
      }
    });
  },

  methods: {
    close() {
      this.instance.autocomplete('close');
    },

    getOption(optionName) {
      return this.instance.autocomplete('option', optionName);
    },

    search(keyword) {
      this.instance.autocomplete('search', keyword);
    },

    disable(toState) {
      this.instance.autocomplete('option', 'disabled', toState);
    }
  },

  watch: {
    source(newData, oldData) {
      this.instance.autocomplete('option', 'source', newData);
    },

    disabled(newState, oldState) {
      this.disable(newState);
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data: () => ({
    items: [
      'vue',
      'react',
      'angular',
      'jquery'
    ],
    disabled: false
  }),

  computed: {
    computedItems: {
      get() {
        return this.items.join(', ');
      },
      set(val) {
        this.items = val.split(', ')
      }
    }
  },

  methods: {
    onChange() {
      // Do something
    },

    onFocus() {},

    onSelect(instance, event, ui) {
      console.log(`You selected: "${ui.item.value}"`);
    }
  },

  components: {
    Autocomplete
  }
})
```

```css
#app {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#app > div {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />

<script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <autocomplete
    v-model="items"
    :disabled="disabled"
    label='Type something (e.g. "ue")'
    @change="onChange"
    @focus="onFocus"
    @select="onSelect">
  </autocomplete>

  <div>
    <p>Edit this comma-separated list of items and see them reflected on the component</p>

    <textarea 
      v-model.lazy="computedItems"
      cols="30"
      rows="3">
    </textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

P.S. If these widgets are actually in the global `window` scope **and** you are using ESLint, you'll want to ensure they are specified as global variables; otherwise, the `no-undef` rule will warn on variables that are accessed but not defined within the same file. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64915112/3634538) for the solution.

P.P.S. If you need to ship them as a plugin, see: [Writing a Plugin](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html#Writing-a-Plugin) (don't worry, there won't be much extra work required).